# Can't set "android:background" attribute with databinding, get a "object] cannot be converted to View" error

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a Textview like so:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@{message.isSelf() ? @drawable/bubble_blue : @drawable/bubble_grey}"/>
```

And the message.isSelf() is just a public method that returns a boolean.

However, I get this error when trying to compile:

```
Error:(125, 141) error: incompatible types: Message cannot be converted to View
```

Going into source code for the error, this is the problem line in the generated databinding

```
var = ((messageIsSelf) ? (getDrawableFromResource(message, R.drawable.bubble_blue)) : (getDrawableFromResource(message, R.drawable.bubble_grey)));
```

The method getDrawableFromResource takes a View and drawable ID as a parameter:

```
 /** @hide */
    protected static Drawable getDrawableFromResource(View view, int resourceId) {
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            return view.getContext().getDrawable(resourceId);
        } else {
            return view.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
        }
    }
```

For some reason, my message object is being passed to the method instead of a view. How do I fix this? I've tried deleting the build folder but still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out its because I had both a "message" object and the id of the TextView defined as "message" which was causing the conflict. Changing the id solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
getDrawableFromResource(message, R.drawable.bubble_grey)));
```

In the above method you send a `Message` object (I assume `message` is a `Message` object), but the method requires a `View` object (according to the code you provided). This is why you get that error.

Try to use `@android:drawable` annotation:

```
<TextView 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:background="@{message.isSelf() ? 
                       @android:drawable/bubble_blue : 
                       @android:drawable/bubble_grey}"
/>
```